# Arduino Uno R3 + Android multiple LED blink can turn on but wont go off

Tags: arduino, led, android, usb-host

I'm new here and I have a question...I hope you could help me, any answer is more than welcome...so I am using an android app with switches to turn on and off 5 LEDs...I managed to turn on four of them, but none of them won't to turn off when I press the switch again in my app... a think that something is wrong with my arduino sketch...p.s. in my app in send command I can send also command from seekbar but I am not using it I mean I didn't put it in app.

```
This is Arduino code. 
#include <adk.h>
USB Usb;
ADK adk(&Usb, "test", // Manufacturer Name
              "test", // Model Name
              "Example sketch for the USB Host Shield", 
              "1.0", // Version
               "http://www.tkjelectronics.dk/uploads/ArduinoBlinkLED.apk", 
               "0000000012345678"); // Serial Number (optional)
const int LED1 =  9;
const int LED2 =  4;
const int LED3 =  7;
const int LED4 =  8;
const int LED5 =  3;
uint32_t timer;
boolean connected;
void setup() {

   Serial.begin(115200);
   while (!Serial); 
   if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
      Serial.print("\r\nOSCOKIRQ failed to assert");
      while (1); // halt
   }
pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED5, OUTPUT);
Serial.print("\r\nArduino Blink LED Started");
}

void loop() {
Usb.Task();

if (adk.isReady()) {
  if (!connected) {
    connected = true;
    Serial.print(F("\r\nConnected to accessory"));
}


uint8_t msg[3]={0x0};
uint16_t len = sizeof(msg);
uint8_t rcode = adk.RcvData(&len, msg);
if( rcode ) {
 USBTRACE2("Data rcv. :", rcode );}
if (len > 0) {    
   USBTRACE("\r\nData Packet.");
   // assumes only one command per packet  
   if (msg[1] == 0x2)
       digitalWrite(LED1, msg[0]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);
   else if (msg[1] == 0x3)
   digitalWrite(LED2, msg[0]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);
   else if (msg[1] == 0x4)
   digitalWrite(LED3, msg[0]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);
   else if (msg[1] == 0x5)
   digitalWrite(LED4, msg[0]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);
    else if (msg[1] == 0x6)
   digitalWrite(LED5, msg[0]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);
}

msg[0] = 0x1;   


if (millis() - timer >= 1000) { // Send data every 1s
  timer = millis();
  rcode = adk.SndData(sizeof(timer), (uint8_t*)&timer);
  if (rcode && rcode != hrNAK) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nData send: "));
    Serial.print(rcode, HEX);
  } else if (rcode != hrNAK) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nTimer: "));
    Serial.print(timer);
  }
}
} else {
    if (connected) {
    connected = false;
    Serial.print(F("\r\nDisconnected from accessory"));
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
    }
 }
}
```

and my android app main activity

```
private final byte digitalPort = 0x1;
private final byte outputHighLow = 0x0;
private final byte outputPWM = 0x1;
private final byte low = 0x0;
private final byte high = 0x1;

private Switch switch1,switch2,switch3,switch4,switch5;

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener highLowChangeListener = new HighLowChangeListener();

  ....... some code for usb accessory


protected void showControls() {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    switch1.setTag((byte) 0x2);
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(highLowChangeListener);
    switch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    switch2.setTag((byte) 0x3);
    switch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(highLowChangeListener);
    switch3 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch3);
    switch3.setTag((byte) 0x4);
    switch3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(highLowChangeListener);
    switch4 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch4);
    switch4.setTag((byte) 0x5);
    switch4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(highLowChangeListener);
    switch5 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch5);
    switch5.setTag((byte) 0x6);
    switch5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(highLowChangeListener);
}


private class HighLowChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        byte portByte = (Byte) buttonView.getTag();
        if (isChecked) {
            sendCommand(digitalPort, portByte, outputHighLow, high);
            Log.i(TAG, "message send: digital pin " + portByte + " HIGH");
        } else {
            sendCommand(digitalPort, portByte, outputHighLow, low);
            Log.i(TAG, "message send: digital pin " + portByte + " LOW");
        }
    }
}


public void sendCommand(byte portType, byte portNumber, byte mode, byte value) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    if (value > 255)
        value = (byte)255;
    buffer[0] = portType;
    buffer[1] = portNumber;
    buffer[2] = mode;
    buffer[3] = value;
    Log.i(TAG, "byte: " + buffer[0]);
    Log.i(TAG, "byte: " + buffer[1]);
    Log.i(TAG, "byte: " + buffer[2]);
    Log.i(TAG, "byte: " + buffer[3]);
    if (mOutputStream != null && buffer[1] != -1) {
        try {
            mOutputStream.write(buffer);
            mOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "write failed", e);
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: That is way too much code to just dump here and hope for people to want to go through. Narrow it down to the part that is actually the problem.

Comment: Is this better? :) btw thx for advice is better this way

Answer (score 3):

I haven't trawled through all your code, but one immediate mistake I see is this:

```
uint8_t msg[3]={0x0};
...
digitalWrite(LED4, msg[3]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);
```

You allocate an array of 3 bytes (slices 0..2) and then reference slice 3, which is the 4th byte of a 3-byte array.

Comment: oh yes i see that now ... it should be than like this:

     uint8_t msg[3]={0x0};
     ...
     digitalWrite(LED4, msg[0]==0x1 ? HIGH : LOW);

i am sorry if i didnt understand you well cause this is not my mother thounge so it a bit difficult :)

Comment: He means that arrays are initialized with "3" has 3 objects, but are addressed starting with 0. Msg[0], msg[1], msg[2] are valid. Msg[3] is out of bounds error.

Comment: Aha. Ok I have understood that but when I change it to msg[0] or msg[1] or msg[2] problem remains the same. I  remebered that this isn`t the source of the problem because i was trying to fix it and i edited program but when I wanted to upload it here i didn`t restore all back to the begining

Comment: Ok here is another try with serial monitor.... Connected to accessory Data Packet: 11 Data Packet: 11 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 1 Data Packet: 11 Data Packet: 11 Data rcv: D Data rcv: D So for LED4 is Data Packet:11 when I press turn on switch and when i press off it also say data packet:11 for LED4.... the Data Packet:1 is for the same actions but with other LEDs which are not connected to board at this point